# Progressbar and Textview won't dissapear after finishing loading

Tags: android, textview, progress-bar, media-player, loading

i have a media player with a progressbars that show how much it has loaded but the progress bar and textview won't go away after finishing loading.

here is the code

*EDIT - CODE WORKS NOW*

```
private void initView() {
    Pbar = (ProgressBar)  findViewById(R.id.progressBar01);
    Pbar.setMax(100);
    txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView01);
}


public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {            
             {
             if(percent < 100){
                 Pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
             Pbar.setProgress(percent);
             if(percent == 100) {
                 Pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 txtview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             }
         }      
    }
```

Thx :P

Comment: Percent must never get 100? Is there another method you can override. What is the type of this class that you are in?

Comment: Just making sure but does this method get called at all? You could try doing an else instead of an if( percent == 100 ).

Answer (score 1):

Look for another listener you can use.

How about:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html

I assume this will be called after it has done a buffer update.

```
public void onPrepared() {
      Pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      txtview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```